# Display ad every n items in RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I want to display an ad every n items on my RecyclerAdapter.

I'm expecting this

```
|----- Item 0 -----|
|------- AD -------|
|----- Item 1 -----|
|----- Item 2 -----|
|----- Item 3 -----|
|----- Item 4 -----|
|----- Item 5 -----|
|------ ... -------|
|----- Item 15 ----|
|------- AD -------|
|----- Item 16 ----|
|------ ... -------|
```

But with a fast scroll I can have something like that

```
|----- Item 0 -----|
|------- AD -------|
|----- Item 1 -----|
|----- Item 2 -----|
|----- Item 3 -----|
|------ ... -------|
|---- Item 241 ----|
|------- AD -------|
|------ ... -------|
```

If I'm scrolling slowly ads are displayed after every 15 items.
But if I'm scrolling fastly ads are displayed not correctly. For example an ad is displayed after item n°241, and 241 % 15 is not equal to 0.

Is it probably a problem due to view reuse, I am probably doing it wrong but I don't know how I can do it otherwise.

Here is my adapter code.

```
public class MyCursorRecyclerAdapter extends CursorRecyclerAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int AD_POS = 15;

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

class ViewHolderItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mTextView;
    public LinearLayout mLayout;

    public ViewHolderItem(View layout) {
        super(layout);
        mTextView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        mLayout = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.main_linear_layout);
    }
}

public MyCursorRecyclerAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(c);
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.listview_item_layout, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolderItem(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolderCursor(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holderDefault, Cursor cursor) {

    int cursorPosition = cursor.getPosition();

    final ViewHolderItem holder = (ViewHolderItem) holderDefault;
    final String text = cursorPosition + " : "+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyTable.MY_COLUMN));

    holder.mTextView.setText(text);

    final ViewGroup layout = ((ViewHolderItem) holderDefault).mLayout;

    if (cursorPosition % AD_POS == 0) {
        NativeAd ad = new NativeAd(mContext, "ID");
        ad.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                mInflater.inflate(R.layout.native_ad_layout, layout);
                AdManager.inflateAd((NativeAd) ad, layout, mContext);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {}
        });
        ad.loadAd();
    } else {
        int childCount = layout.getChildCount();
        if (layout.getChildAt(childCount-1).getId() == R.id.adUnit) {
            layout.removeViewAt(childCount-1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The better way is use `getItemViewType(int position)` method.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(cursorPosition % AD_POS == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And after that you have to use viewType param in `onCreateViewHolder` method, to recognise which view you have to inflate as is shown in code below:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType ==0){
         View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.listview_item_layout, parent, false);    
    } else if(viewType ==1){ 
         View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.different_layout, parent, false); 
    }

    return new ViewHolderItem(v);
}
```

And additionally you have to support second layout in `ViewHolderItem` or create `SecondViewHolderItem` and return proper ViewHolder in method above and cast to proper `ViewHolder` in `onBindViewHolderCursor` method depend on the position of.

And you have to take into account these items in `getItemCount()` method.

Comment: If I have 100 items in my database and I want to display an ad every 10 items. I will have 110 items in my listview ? Or 100? Do I have to override getItemCount() to increment it by 10 ?

Comment: Yes I forgot about this. You have to take into account these items in getItemCount() method

Comment: I think it will work but I have a problem with getItemId(int position); I override it to always return 12721 but in my listview I don't see always the same quote.

Comment: Why do you do this? Is it special reason? The Id should be -1 (NO_ID) or should be unique. You can return getItemId() position

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you please accept it or give me upvote :)

Comment: Got it ;) I have to override onBindViewHolder to adapt my logic.

Comment: say, AD_POS is 5, will this method not show an ad in place of the 5th item, it does not take into account the shifting of 5th item ahead or behind right ?

Comment: @divyenduz AD_POS defines position of item which is a type 0. If you have 5 items in list - the last position is 4 because items are indexed from 0

Comment: The thing is that it overrides the 10th item no? how to make sure it adds 1 ad after every 10